# Laravel different file for DB connections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Laravel uses `config/database.php` to define DB connections,

I have other database connections, and I would like to store those connections in `config/other.php`

And after use it in a model or via function
`$model->setConnection(config('other.fisrt_connection'))`

But I failed doing so.

It is possible to set connection from another config file in laravel 5.1?

And also when DB connection is setted how pass this connection to relationship models?

Comment: Why do you want it in a different file?

Comment: [Check this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections).

Comment: @JosephSilber I know it is strane, but I need to put some data to each connection, like description and etc.

Comment: @TheAlpha hmm didnt get it is still uses config/database.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write all of the DB connection settings to database.php.
Because all DB method reference this file.

It is also possible to selectively use multiple DB connections.
For more information please reference manual page.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections

But, if you want to use the absolutely other files, will need to make a few modifications to the Code of Laravel.
Not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

**Multiple Database Connection**

If your application needs to interact with multiple DB you can define all the required DB details in `app/config/database.php` file. Adding another config file is not recommended.

```
     'connections' => array(
             'mysql1' => array(         // mysql1 -> connection_name
               'driver'    => 'mysql',
               'host'      => 'localhost',
               'database'  => 'example',
               'username'  => 'example',
               'password'  => 'example',
               ..
           ),
             'mysql2' => array(         // mysql2 -> connection_name
               'driver'    => 'mysql',
               'host'      => 'localhost',
               'database'  => 'example2',
               'username'  => 'example2',
               'password'  => 'example2',
               ..
          ),
       ),
```

When writing queries you can connect to the required DB likewise:

***If Query Builder***

```
$users = DB::connection('connection_name')->select(...);
```

***Eloquent***

*Within the model:*

```
class User extends Eloquent {    
    protected $connection = 'connection_name';    
}
```

*When trying to fetch values use as follows*

```
$userModel = new User();
$userModel->setConnection('connection_name');
$result = $userModel->newQuery()->find(1);
```

Laravel [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections)

Hope this would get you started.